# Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I am trying to run apache ignite cluster using Google Kubernetes Engine.

After following the tutorial here are some **yaml** files.

First I create a service -
**ignite-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # Name of Ignite Service used by Kubernetes IP finder. 
  # The name must be equal to TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.serviceName.
  name: ignite
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None # custom value.
  ports:
    - port: 9042 # custom value.
  selector:
    # Must be equal to one of the labels set in Ignite pods'
    # deployement configuration.
    app: ignite
```

**`kubectl create -f ignite-service.yaml`**

Second, I create a deployment for my ignite nodes **ignite-deployment.yaml**

## An example of a Kubernetes configuration for Ignite pods deployment.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # Custom Ignite cluster's name.
  name: ignite-cluster
spec:
  # A number of Ignite pods to be started by Kubernetes initially.
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ignite
    spec:
      containers:
        # Custom Ignite pod name.
      - name: ignite-node
        image: apacheignite/ignite:2.4.0
        env:
        - name: OPTION_LIBS
          value: ignite-kubernetes
        - name: CONFIG_URI
          value: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube.xml
        ports:
        # Ports to open.
        # Might be optional depending on your Kubernetes environment.
        - containerPort: 11211 # REST port number.
        - containerPort: 47100 # communication SPI port number.
        - containerPort: 47500 # discovery SPI port number.
        - containerPort: 49112 # JMX port number.
        - containerPort: 10800 # SQL port number.
```

**`kubectl create -f ignite-deployment.yaml`**

After that I check status of my pods which are running in my case. However when I check logs for any of my pod, I get the following error,

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/endpoints/ignite
```

Things I have tried:-

1. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395481/how-to-setmasterurl-in-ignite-xml-config-for-kubernetes-ipfinder/49405879#49405879) to make my cluster work. But in step 4, when I run the daemon yaml file, I get the following error

`error: error validating "daemon.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(DaemonSet.spec.template.spec): missing required field "containers" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

Can anybody point me to my mistake which I might be doing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step 1: `kubectl apply -f ignite-service.yaml` (with the file in your question)

Step 2: `kubectl apply -f ignite-rbac.yaml`

ignite-rbac.yaml is like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ignite
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ignite-endpoint-access
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: ignite
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["endpoints"]
    resourceNames: ["ignite"]
    verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ignite-role-binding
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: ignite
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ignite
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: ignite-endpoint-access
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Step 3: `kubectl apply -f ignite-deployment.yaml` (very similar to your file, I've only added one line, `serviceAccount: ignite`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # Custom Ignite cluster's name.
  name: ignite-cluster
  namespace: default
spec:
  # A number of Ignite pods to be started by Kubernetes initially.
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ignite
    spec:
      serviceAccount: ignite  ## Added line
      containers:
        # Custom Ignite pod name.
      - name: ignite-node
        image: apacheignite/ignite:2.4.0
        env:
        - name: OPTION_LIBS
          value: ignite-kubernetes
        - name: CONFIG_URI
          value: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube.xml
        ports:
        # Ports to open.
        # Might be optional depending on your Kubernetes environment.
        - containerPort: 11211 # REST port number.
        - containerPort: 47100 # communication SPI port number.
        - containerPort: 47500 # discovery SPI port number.
        - containerPort: 49112 # JMX port number.
        - containerPort: 10800 # SQL port number.
```

This should work fine. I've got this in the logs of the pod (`kubectl logs -f ignite-cluster-xx-yy`), showing the 2 Pods successfully locating each other:

```
[13:42:00] Ignite node started OK (id=f89698d6)
[13:42:00] Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=1, offheap=0.72GB, heap=1.0GB]
[13:42:00] Data Regions Configured:
[13:42:00]   ^-- default [initSize=256.0 MiB, maxSize=740.8 MiB, persistenceEnabled=false]
[13:42:01] Topology snapshot [ver=2, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=2, offheap=1.4GB, heap=2.0GB]
[13:42:01] Data Regions Configured:
[13:42:01]   ^-- default [initSize=256.0 MiB, maxSize=740.8 MiB, persistenceEnabled=false]
```

Comment: will clusterrole and clusterrolebinding work for this case as well?

Comment: It would, but it's unnecessary. clusterrole and clusterrolebinding are for cases when an application needs cluster wide access to some resources. For example, an Ingress controller would need access to all Ingress objects in all namespaces, not just a specific one. All that ignite needs is to be able to find it's peers in the same service; we can grant more access but that would be asking for trouble. Say we grant cluster admin privileges to ignite. It would work, but if there's ever a security bug in ignite a malicious actor will be able to take over the whole cluster with ease.

Comment: Now I have ignite cluster running on my GKE. But I need to connect my spark client/job to access ignite server. Do you have any idea about to do that?

Comment: Post a new question and include as much detail as you can, including what you've tried, errors, etc

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968087/spark-executors-not-able-to-access-ignite-nodes-inside-kubernetes-cluster/50979688#50979688