# Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses when running spark client

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, ignite

I have an ignite cluster running on **Google Kubernetes Engine**.

`sudo kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ignite-cluster-bbb4f56c4-nrftv   1/1       Running   0          6d
ignite-cluster-bbb4f56c4-skvf6   1/1       Running   0          6d`

Now I am trying to connect use `igniteRDD` on `spark` using [this](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/ignite/scalar/examples/spark/ScalarSharedRDDExample.scala) `scala` code.

Here is my configuration file which I use to detect ignite pods on GKE cluster.

```
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder

object igniteConf {

  def ignite_configuration: IgniteConfiguration = {
    val spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
    val ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder
    ipFinder.setMasterUrl("https://35.192.214.68")
    ipFinder.setServiceName("ignite")
    spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder)
    val cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi)
    cfg
  }

}
```

and in the main file I use it like this

```
val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(sparkContext, () => igniteConf.ignite_configuration, true)
```

Now I create a jar and after creating a docker image push to **Google Container Registry**.

Command to run the jar.

```
sudo bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://35.192.214.68 --deploy-mode cluster --name sparkIgnite --class org.blk.igniteSparkResearch.ScalarSharedRDDExample --conf spark.executor.instances=3 --conf spark.app.name=sharedSparkIgnite --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=ignite --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=us.gcr.io/nlp-research-198620/ignite-spark:v2 local:///opt/spark/jars/igniteSpark-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

The above command creates 1 driver and 3 executors. Logs of any executors shows that it can't connect to ignite-cluster on kubernetes.

```
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://35.192.214.68/api/v1/namespaces/default/endpoints/ignite
```

Can anybody let me know where I might be going.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setMasterUrl in Ignite XML config for Kubernetes IPFinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395481/how-to-setmasterurl-in-ignite-xml-config-for-kubernetes-ipfinder)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. It's permission-related.

Here is a JIRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8081

You can find a working configuration in a comment.

Comment: I think the link you shared is used for setting up ignite cluster. I already have ignite cluster running but my task is to connect spark client/job to existing ignite cluster on kubernetes.

Comment: From the error you provided I see, that TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder fails to retrieve the list of available Ignite pods. This is exactly the issue, that's described in the ticket.

Comment: So my question is how to access ignite cluster within spark application on Google Kubernetes Engine. All these mentioned issues only provide a partial solution to my problem.

Comment: The code, that you provided, seems legit. The only thing, that doesn't let you run the example is a failing IP finder. Or do you have some other problem?

Comment: It's the failing IP finder problem. I guess its due to RBAC issue since 403 is probably due to it only.

Comment: Also a working configuration was provided in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50979688/6708961