# Spark executors not able to access ignite nodes inside kubernetes cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, ignite

I am connecting my spark job with an existing ignite cluster. I use a service account name **spark** for it. My driver is able to access the ignite pods, but my executors are not able to access that.

This is what executor log looks like

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://35.192.214.68/api/v1/namespaces/default/endpoints/ignite`

I guess it's due to some privileges. Is there a way to explicitly specify service account for executors as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The similar issue was discussed [here](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Unable-to-connect-ignite-pods-in-Kubernetes-using-Ip-finder-td18009.html).

Most likely you need to grant more permissions to a service account which is used for running Ignite.

This way you are able to create and bind one more role to the service account:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ignite
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources: # Here is resources you can access
  - pods
  - endpoints
  verbs: # That is what you can do with them
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

---

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ignite
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ignite
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: <service account name>
  namespace: default
```

Also, if your namespace is not `default` you need to update that one in yaml-files and specify it in [TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder configuration](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-deployment#section-deploying-on-openshift).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already given these permissions to my service account ignite. My problem here is that my spark driver is able to access the ignite cluster but my executors aren't able to do that.

Comment: Probably executors use a default service account. You can check that by the command `kubectl get pod <executor pod name> -o yaml`. Did you try to add ignite role to default service account?

Comment: Yes, I have given cluster role to ignite service account but not to default service account.